# Problema matemático en RGB

Tags: vb.net, matemáticas

Quiero dejar una pequeña duda matemática ya que no lo estoy "viendo" de la manera adecuada.

Contexto: Mi programa recoge ciertas coordenadas para dibujar, junto a las coordenadas viene la presión (P) que es el factor que de verdad importa.

Yo recojo el valor mínimo y el máximo de presión de la lista (Máximo : 0.806495 y Mínimo : 0.00866805) y lo comparo con mi presión (P).

La idea es : Si se escribe a presión máxima (Ma 0.806495) tenga el valor RGB(255,0,0) y en el caso de ser minima RGB(0,255,0). Esta parte el programa lo cumple exitosamente.

El caso es : Como hago que se determine el valor intermedio?

(Lo he intentado mediante un regla de tres, pero con esta solución solo calculo el máximo, ya que le indico que el máximo es 100 y mi presión es X).

En el caso del verde, como tendría que hacerlo? (porque si Mi:0.00866805 es 0 entonces X me daría infinito)

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque ya lo hayas solucionado, te comento como con una regla de 3 lo solucionas rapidamente...

```
    Const MAXIMO As Single = 0.806495
    Const MINIMO As Single = 0.00866805
    Dim presionActual As Single = 0.5 'Aquí tu valor de presión, por ejemplo 0.5

    Dim color As Byte = (255 * (presionActual - MINIMO)) / (MAXIMO - MINIMO)
```

Así consigues un valor de 0 a 255 según la presión actual, para el valor inverso solo tienes que restar el color a 255...

```
RGB(color, 255 - color, 0)
```

Comment: Sin duda la solución más lógica y sencilla, borro mi solución y dejo la tuya.
Muchas gracias!